# Best Solution to work with Dates in React/Node/Mongo/Mongoose app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I work on the following tech stack.

1. **React** - for frontend
2. **Node/Express** - For Middle Tier
3. **MongoDB** - database
4. **Mongoose Driver** - to connect the express app to Mongo DB

I use some date picker components to display dates in the UI, which the users can change. I would like to know what is the best way to post dates to the server, and persist in the DB and likewise, how to query for collections with the date formats using mongoose in the express app.

Please suggest consistent and best possible solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have plenty of options for dates. You can stay super lean and deal with them yourself via [JS Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or use [`momentJS`](http://momentjs.com/docs/) and its tons of plug-ins or go fully functional and light with [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started).

All of these `can be used on the client and on the server`. `momentJS / date-fns` have tons of convenient methods that would save you a lot of time and headaches. `date-fns` can also be partially imported so you do not need the entire lib if you only want few methods.

Saving the dates ... the recommended way is to use the default [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date) for mongoDB when persisting them (which is mongoDB default anyway). Saving them as `strings` is **not really a recommended thing** but you could and you would still be ok as long as you are on **version 3.6+** since there and above they added tons of date/string manipulation functions which would save you tons of time if you have to go back and forth from string to date and vise versa. It is best however to deal with dates from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Date.now() (epoch or utc) both on the server side and client side js. [Date fns](https://date-fns.org/) is a good light-weight js library that works both in node and react js.

Comment: Can I save epoch Time format in MongoDB as string, in that case?

Comment: @BadriNarayananSridharan are you using mongoose(https://mongoosejs.com/)? if yes, just save it as dateNow: Date.now()